# EntLibContrib and OdpNet

Tags: .net, enterprise-library, odp.net, sys-refcursor

I'm trying to get a ref cursor returned from a oracle procedure back to my .Net app, but I keep getting an error regarding the wrong number of parameters.

The oracle procedure has the following params:

```
PROCEDURE sp_user_list(pv_username     IN VARCHAR2
                        ,pn_result      OUT NUMBER
                        ,pv_error       OUT VARCHAR2
                        ,pref_user_list OUT SYS_REFCURSOR);
```

My data access code is :

```
public int GetUserID(string sUserName)
        {
            int iUserID = 0;

            Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();

            string sql = "pk_quality.sp_user_list";
            DbCommand cmd = db.GetStoredProcCommand(sql);

            db.AddInParameter(cmd, "pv_username", DbType.String, sUserName);
            db.AddOutParameter(cmd, "pn_result", DbType.Int32, 2);
            db.AddOutParameter(cmd, "pv_error", DbType.String, 500);


            using (IDataReader dataReader = db.ExecuteReader(cmd))
            {
                while (dataReader.Read())
                {
                    iUserID = int.Parse(dataReader["user_id"].ToString());
                }
            }

            return iUserID;
        }
```

There doesn't seem to be any ref cursor dbtype to allow me to add an out parameter to handle the ref cursor. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the refcursor output parameter as well to the command object.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(
     new OracleParameter("pref_user_list", 
                         OracleDbType.RefCursor, 
                         ParameterDirection.Output));
```

This works with ODP.NET data provider. The DbType enum doesn't have a corresponding type for refcursor. But, adding Oracle reference to data access class may look like violating the DAAB principle.